# Add slope to sub-plots of multi-graph plot in R

Tags: r

I have longitudinal data of a single variable ("**Count**") vs time ("**Days**") from several individuals ("**ID"**), and a block of code that produces a plot with a separate graph of **Count** for each individual. In some cases, some datapoints are flagged with "1" under the variable "**Treat**", and are plotted in red. The others have **Treat** value = 0.

My problem: I need to a) add a regression line to each plot, using only the datapoints that have **Treat** = 0, and b) need to print the slope of the line on each subplot. I am not sure how to do this. My code so far:

```
#plot longitudinal CD4 counts from multiple individuals in separate plots

#Clear work area
rm(list = ls(all = TRUE))

#Enter example data
tC <- textConnection("
ID  VisitDate   Count   Treat   Treatstarted
C0098   12-Feb-10   457 0   NA
C0098   2-Jul-10    467 0   NA
C0098   7-Oct-10    420 0   NA
C0098   3-Feb-11    357 0   NA
C0098   8-Jun-11    209 0   NA
C0098   9-Jul-11    223 0   NA
C0098   12-Oct-11   309 0   NA
C0110   23-Jun-10   629 0   30-Oct-10
C0110   30-Sep-10   461 0   30-Oct-10
C0110   15-Feb-11   270 1   30-Oct-10
C0110   22-Jun-11   236 1   30-Oct-10
C0151   2-Feb-10    199 0   NA
C0151   24-Mar-10   936 0   3-Apr-10
C0151   7-Jul-10    1147    1   3-Apr-10
C0151   9-Mar-11    1192    1   3-Apr-10
")
data1 <- read.table(header=TRUE, tC)
close.connection(tC)

# calculate elapsed time from first date, by ID
data1$VisitDate <- with(data1,as.Date(VisitDate,format="%d-%b-%y"))
data1$Days <- unlist(with(data1,tapply(VisitDate,ID,function(x){x-x[1]})))

#Define plot function
plot_one <- function(d){
 with(d, plot(Days, Count, t="n", tck=1, main=unique(d$ID), cex.main = 0.8, ylab = "", yaxt = 'n', xlab = "", xaxt="n",  xlim=c(0,1000), ylim=c(0,1200))) # set limits
    grid(lwd = 0.3, lty = 7)
    with(d[d$Treat == 0,], points(Days, Count, col = 1)) 
    with(d[d$Treat == 1,], points(Days, Count, col = 2))
}

#Create multiple plot figure
par(mfrow=c(8,8), oma = c(0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5), mar = c(0.5,0.5,0.5,0.5))
plyr::d_ply(data1, "ID", plot_one)
```

Thoughts greatly appreciated

Comment: Have a look at `?abline`. In addition to the `reg` argument (which is explained in the Details section), there are examples near the bottom of the page that explain how to add simple regression lines to plots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a slight modification to your `plot_one` function should do the trick.

```
plot_one <- function(d){
  with(d, plot(Days, Count, t="n", tck=1, main=unique(d$ID), cex.main = 0.8, ylab = "", yaxt = 'n', xlab = "", xaxt="n",  xlim=c(0,1000), ylim=c(0,1200))) # set limits
  grid(lwd = 0.3, lty = 7)
  with(d[d$Treat == 0,], points(Days, Count, col = 1)) 
  with(d[d$Treat == 1,], points(Days, Count, col = 2))
  mod = lm(Count ~ Days, data = d[d$Treat == 0,])
  abline(reg = mod)
  text(x=500, y=800, mod$coefficients[2])
}
```

Which gives the following graph (I changed the par to make it a little bigger):

[image]